# Plotly Python go.Heatmap 'x' input not matching x-axis

Tags: plotly, plotly-python

I am supplying x, y, and z input to go.Heatmap, and I am getting unexpected widths for my heatmap.

Here is my jupyter code:

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import numpy as np
import datetime


x = [10,20,30,60]


z1 = [ 0.25,0.50,0.75, 1.0]


z = [z1]
y = ['blah1']

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Heatmap( z=z, x=x, y=y, colorscale='turbo', zmin=0, zmax=1.2,))
fig.update_layout(template="plotly_dark", width=500, height=500, paper_bgcolor="rgb(37,37,38)", margin=dict(l=10, r=10, t=20, b=20))

fig.show()
```

And this is what I am seeing:

[Chart image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKCGv.png)

I would have expected the yellow bar to be the same width as the blue and green. I.e. I was expecting the x to actually be x-axis values. The hoverdata shows the x value as 30, but that doesn't seem to line up with the x-axis.

Is this a bug, or am I interpreting what the x values are supposed to be doing?

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have figured it out.

From: https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/heatmap/
". Moreover, `x` (`y`) can be provided with M or M+1 (N or N+1) elements. If M (N), then the coordinates correspond to the center of the heatmap cells and the cells have equal width. **If M+1 (N+1), then the coordinates correspond to the edges of the heatmap cells.**"

My x inputs are had M entries, when they needed to have M+1
Changing it to: x = [0,10,20,30,60] solved my problem